# How can I share a link to facebook using native app on browser

Tags: facebook, share, mobile-browser, nativeapplication

I want to make a button sharing a link to facebook on android mobile web site via native facebook app.

I found "fb://publish" url can open native app. 
but I couldn't find How to send image, title, description like meta tag information to native app.

If anyone know how to do this, please let me know

thanks.